# Best way to add low voltage outlet to wall that has blown in insulation on the other side?

Tags: insulation, low-voltage

I want to add a wireless AP and plop it on top of the cabinets in my kitchen; thing is the wall I want to add the low voltage outlet to had blown in insulation on the other side. (The ceiling is vaulted in the kitchen, and the ajoining room it is not, so this is still a vertical wall in the kitchen side) Problem is, low voltage "boxes" are just plastic rectangles to hold the wall-plate, I basically am knocking a 2"x3" hole in a quasi-external wall.

I want to minimize heat loss, and I'd also, if possible, like to make it so I don't spill insulation into the house every time I have to take off the plate.

What is the ideal solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a regular box instead of the low voltage box. Specifically, I would suggest getting an old work draft tight box, like this one. They have gaskets at the cable passthroughs to keep drafts/moisture from going through the box.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A wireless AP that is power via PoE.  Connect a power injector on the source end of the RJ45 or get a PoE supporting router.

Then you only need a hole large enough to poke a network cable through.

PoE+. PoE+, or 802.3at, provides up to 30W of power to powered devices.

The upcoming IEEE 802.3bt aka 4PPoE (4 Pair Power over Ethernet) standard will introduce two new levels of power: 55 W (Level 3) and 90-100 W (Level 4).”

Depending on your access point this may or may not be viable option.

You maybe able to use this 48v to 12v @ 2A to power your AP.

[https://www.amazon.com/ANVISION-Splitter-Ethernet-Security-AV-PS12-G/dp/B07W87KSFQ/ref=sr_1_5?keywords=gigabit+poe+to+12v+adapter&qid=1575563331&sr=8-5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07W87KSFQ)
[image]

[https://www.amazon.com/ANVISION-Splitter-Multi-Size-1000Mbps-Compliant/dp/B01JCKHIGM/ref=sr_1_13?crid=2ANY0RN4U0G7M&keywords=12v+poe+splitter+gigabit&qid=1575563721&sprefix=gigabit+poe+to+12v%2Caps%2C148&sr=8-13](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01JCKHIGM)